# Using Elasticsearch as the search engine for data stored in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I am using Mongodb as database and want to search data using Elasticsearch. In Mongodb I have a collection **api1** stored in database **ayush2**.

Snapshot of the database I want to index:

[image: Snapshot of the database I want to index]

So far I have successfully integrated mongodb with elasticsearch using mongo-connector. I am saying *successfully* since when searched for indices ( using **GET /_cat/indices**) on kibana console the name of the database appears as an index

Snapshot of output in kibana console:

[image: Snapshot of output in kibana console]

Now I am stuck since I do not know how to go ahead from here to search through the database.

Comment: did you try to list documents from ayush2 index?  also I observed status is yellow not green.

Comment: Yes i did. Turns out i am able to search through collection. But my ultimate aim is indexing the data in elasticsearch for efficient searching.